# Accessing deep values from array

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-modules, drupal-themes

I have a basic template node--some-name.html.twig, which I am trying to access a specific value from a child of the content variable.

```
{% for item in content %}
  {{ kint(item) }}
{% endfor %}
```

which prints an expected value like so (trimmed for brevity):

```
Array
(
    [#title] => Body
    [#language] => en
    [#field_name] => body
    [#field_type] => text_with_summary
    [#field_translatable] => 1
    [#entity_type] => node
    [#object] => stdClass Object
        (
            [__CLASS__] => Drupal\node\Entity\Node
            [in_preview] => 
            [values:protected] => Array
                (
                    [body] => Array
                        (
                            [x-default] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [value] => Body sample goes here
                                            [summary] => summary sample here
                                            [format] => rich_text
                                        )

                                )

                        )
                )
        )
)
```

but if I try to print them in my loop it only returns null... am I missing something super basic?

```
{% for item in content %}
  {{ item["#object"].values.body[0].value }}
  {{ item["#object"]["values"]["body"][0].value }}
{% endfor %}
```

printing `{{item}}` gives the entire item as expected but trying to access specific deeper properties of `item` seems to be null regardless of property or how I've accessed it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The property `values` in your class is protected, meaning `twig` will not be able to access this property unless:

- You make the property `values` `public`
- You create a public getter `getValues` in your class

As seen in the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#variables)